# Problem with iteration on array in For loop

Tags: c++, arrays, for-loop

I'm having a trouble for a long time in a problem related to array and loops.

Assume an array like:

```
int arr[] = {2, 3, 5, 3, 6, 8, 10, 1, 9};
```

The program should print the `expected` column as shown (note that the table is an idea for clarification of what I actually want to achieve):

```
max:  expected    arr[index] for max
------------------------------------
 2 :  3 5         value of: arr[0]
 3 :  6, 8, 10    value of: arr[3]
 1 :  9           value of: arr[7]
```

This is what I've tried so far:

```
#include <iostream>

int main(void) {
    int arr[] = {2, 3, 5, 3, 6, 8, 10, 1, 9};
    int max = arr[0];
    int i = 1, it = i;

    for (; i <= max; i++) {
        if (i == max) {
            std::cout << arr[i] << std::endl;
            max = arr[it + 1]; // when loop end has come, increment max to next element value
            it = i + 2; // incrementing iterator by 2 next element position (after max)

        } else {
            std::cout << arr[i] << ' '; // when loop is executing
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

What it actually prints which is unexpected **V/S** what it should print:

```
3 5    |  3, 5
3 6 8  |  6, 8, 10
10 1 9 |  1, 9
10     |  <nothing>
```

The program is about to get max value and print the next elements until `max` value reaches the number of element position.

Where the problem's occurring and how to fix it? Please let me know.

Comment: you put keys and values in the same pot.... that is the perfect recipe for a broken code...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I rewrote your code, frankly I couldn't follow it, it seems a bit confused with variable names that seem a bit off.

Here's some working code. The two key concepts in the code are the place where each block starts (the variable `start`) and the size of each block (the variable `count`). Plus I use the size of the whole array `sizeof(arr)/sizeof(arr[0])` to terminate the outer loop. Something that wasn't present in your code. If you are using C++17, you can use `std::size(arr)` instead of `sizeof`.

```
int main(void) {
    int arr[] = {2, 3, 5, 3, 6, 8, 10, 1, 9};

    size_t start = 0;
    while (start < sizeof(arr)/sizeof(arr[0]))
    {
        int count = arr[start];
        for (int i = 0; i < count; ++i)
        {
            std::cout << arr[start + i + 1] << ' ';
        }
        std::cout << std::endl;
        start += count + 1;
    }
}
```

The output is

```
3 5
6 8 10
9
```